# Can I build a mutable range?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Iterating over mutable objects are changable while being executed:

```
a = [11, 12, 13]

for i in a:
    if i == 12:
        a.append(20)
    print(i)
```

Results with

```
11
12
13
20
```

And `a` is `[11, 12, 13, 20]`

But if I use `range` it is not mutable

```
a = [11, 12, 13]

for i in range(len(a)):
    if i == 1:
        a.append(20)
    print(a[i])
```

Results with

```
11
12
13
```

while `a` is still `[11, 12, 13, 20]` afterwards.

Is there a way to build a `myrange` object that will work the same way as range but will be mutable while executing?

Comment: You don't have a generator in this code. Are you sure you understand what either of your code snippets are doing?

Comment: Be warned: that first code has the potential to cause you a headache if the comparison and the append are the same value. You don't get a warning, but you don't want to mutate a list you're iterating ever...

Comment: @user2357112, I try not to be sure of anything :-). But in this case I think I've just misused the term "generator", which I've now corrected and eliminated from the question.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, and as you said yourself `a` is already mutable, so instead of iterating over a range that's based upon `len(a)` before the loop, you can do the following:

```
for i, val in enumerate(a):
    if i == 1:
        a.append(20)
    print(val)
```

Output:

```
11
12
13
20
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second code snippet:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if i == 1:
        a.append(20)
    print(a[i])
```

when you use `range(len(a))` it returns [0, 1, 2] in this case as the length of `a==3` Now the for loop would be iterated only 3 times as the `len(a)` is executed at the start of the loop which already returned a list of 3 elements and when you update the list the changes are not reflected as `len(a)` is never executed again.

If you print the `a` outside the for loop you will see the appended element (20) at the end of the list.

Whereas in second case you are trying to iterate over the list, which keeps on `yield`ing the results until the whole list is exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

**First Snippet:**
In the first snippet, the iteration actually occurs over each element in a. Thus, when the append statement adds a new item to the list, the loop considers that element as well. Imagine the loop as a pointer that will continue till it reaches the end of the list.

**Second Snippet:**
However, in the second snippet, the iteration occurs over the range of length of the list. When the loop begins, the range has already been calculated. Thus, any change to the list will not really affect the range over which the iteration occurs. Additionally, range as an object itself is immutable.

**Answer:**
I am assuming that what you really want is that you can iterate in such a manner that all new additions to the list get considered, but you get to use the position of the element being considered. For such a situation, I would suggest using a flag variable along with a while loop.

```
a = [11, 12, 13]
counter = 0

while counter < len(a):
    if counter == 1:
        a.append(20)
    print(a[counter])
    counter += 1
```

**Output:**

```
11
12
13
20
```

This works because len(a) is calculated on each iteration, so any changes to the list get accommodated.